# Suggestions for faster deserialization using Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

I am using [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) in order to serialize/deserialize the data. I have defined the Protocol Buffers message file as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package Tutorial;
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message PointCloud {
  int32 width  = 1;
  int32 height = 2;

  message Point {
    float x     = 1;
    float y     = 2;
    float z     = 3;
    fixed32 rgb = 4;
  }
  repeated Point points = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 4;
}
```

I am able to receive the serialized data. I am using [ParseFromArray](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite) API as follows:

```
zmq::message_t msg;
int rc = zmq_socket.recv(&msg);
if (rc){
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Tutorial::PointCloud point_cloud;
    point_cloud.ParseFromArray(msg.data(), msg.size());
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Time (ms): " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count()/1000.0 << std::endl
}
```

The above works but it takes enough time to deserialize the data. On an average it takes around 96 ms in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS. Just for information, I also printed `msg.size()` and found it 3773550 approximately.

**I am looking for suggestions to deserialize the data much faster than this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, there might be no way.

Protobuf is slow to deserialize since it need to construct objects on the fly from a series of key-value pairs. If performance is your concern, try flatbuffer or Capn'Proto. These are alternatives which does not need any object construction but (possibly) cost more on disk, and had other shortcomings.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Based on the code and protocol message above, which do you suggest? *flatbuffer* or *Capn'Proto* ? I have never used any of them. Hence I am looking for expert suggestions.

Comment: @RaviJoshi Both are possible solutions, I strongly suggest you try both and run your own benchmark. There are too many trade-off depending your actual usage model/pattern.